# 2d ordering in unity

Tags: popup, unity-game-engine

i am making a 2d game in unity. 
i am missing a feature that cocos2d has that when you create something in the parent it keeps its z ordering inside that parent. 
the problem that i am experiencing is with popups, when i create a popup or menu i want to make sure that it gets displayed above everything else in the scene or any other popup, but i cant make sure that it does because some elements in the scene may have z value that even though they are inside a parent object may appear above my popups if i am not careful. same goes for popups if i would like to have a popup on top of another popup i will have to make sure that  there are no intersecting children between them.
does anyone know is there any way of containing an object to be rendered only inside its parent z order like cocos2d does? or should this problem be approached differently.

Answer (score 0):

When working in 2D mode in Unity, you should just focus on setting the Order In Layer value of the sprites to have them display as you want. Leave all the z values in 0.